# How do I read a value from user input into a variable

Tags: linux, unix, ksh

In ksh, how do I prompt a user to enter a value, and load that value into a variable within the script?

command line

```
echo Please enter your name:
```

within the script

```
$myName = ?
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want read:

```
echo Please enter your name:
read name
echo $name
```

See [read(1)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/read.html) for more.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it in a single line, like so:

```
read -p "Please enter your name:" myName
```

To use variable in script

```
echo "The name you inputed is: $myName"
echo $myName
```

Comment: this works well on cygwin, but not for ksh on AIX 7.1 - accepted answer from Marcus works on both

Comment: The question has a linux tag, so I'm assuming the OP wants a Linux answer. AIX, a proprietary branch of Unix deved by IBM is not part of Linux. As far as I know this has worked on all the branches of Linux I've worked with and it has the formatting advantage that the first answer doesn't (as using an echo followed by a read statement forces uses  input on a new line whereas read -p does not).

Comment: NOTE: `-p` is not [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html)

Comment: `ksh` does not support `read -p` (or rather, the `-p` option to `read` does something different in `ksh`). This question is clearly tagged [tag:ksh] and it is reinforced in the question text, but you still provided a Bash answer.

Answer (score 0):

`ksh` allows you to specify a prompt as part of the `read` command using this syntax:

```
read myName?"Please provide your name: "
```