# How do I check to see if a file exists within a directory

Tags: linux, unix, scripting, ksh

I what to prompt a user to enter name of a file, read that into a variable, and use that variable to check if the valued enter is in fact a legimate file.

How would I do this in a ksh script? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know already how to [read user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802848/how-do-i-read-a-value-from-user-input-into-a-variable), here's the new part:

It's done with [test(1)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html):

```
test -f $theFile && echo exists
```

It also has the alternate name `[` which is most often used in `if` or `while` expressions:

```
if [ -f $theFile ]
then
    echo exists
fi
```

Please refer to the above link (or alternatively the manual page).